# Why app doesn't see permission Camera2API?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have a really big issue(

I'm working with Camera2API and and I use for it standard Google example.

Mystic is when I use this method

```
private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);

    configureTransform(width, height);
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");

        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}
```

I use `Samsung S6 android 6.0`

I expect that method `manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);` - will open the camera, but instead of this, code is stoping in

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
```

as far as I understand, it means that my manifest does not contain permission, but I checked and there is an appropriate permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

What does it mean?

I have this permission, why it doesn't pass checking?

I tried launching this app on `Meizu MX5 android 5.1` and it opens the camera and everything is ok...

Maybe the problem is in androind version?

What I am doing wrong? How can I check it?

Comment: If you are target Api is 23 you have check Run Time Permission..Take a look this sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're using Android 6.0 right?
According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) even if you declare the permissions in the manifest, you have to individually check for each permission, request each permission if it hasn't been granted.
To do this, after :

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
}
```

Instead of `return` , do this ,

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},YOUR_INTEGER_CONSTANT_FOR_THE_CALLBACK);
```

and implement the callback function as described in the linked page,

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case YOUR_INTEGER_CONSTANT_FOR_THE_CALLBACK: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Granted");
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG,"Denied");
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your Samsung go to your: Setting -> Apps -> "Your app" -> Permissions; and manually set the permissions. This happens when your target API is 23 and above. It will run ok on lower versions. If you want to make your app be granted permissions automatically on android 6.0 and above, in your `gradle` change the target API to 22. Also it would be better to implement in your app asking for permissions.